# Trouble with mup deploy on AWS-EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, npm, mup

I am trying to deploy meteor-react-app on Amazon Web Services. 
Mup setup results in,

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Docker
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Environment
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Environment
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Copying mongodb.conf
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Start Mongo
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Start Mongo: SUCCESS

Next, you should run:
mup deploy
```

But when I am running mup deploy, it is suggesting me to add npm packages.

```
Building App Bundle Locally

Unable to resolve some modules:

"babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/imports/adminDashboard/dashboard/components/AdminHeader.jsx(web.browser)
"babel-runtime/helpers/inherits" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/imports/adminDashboard/dashboard/components /AdminHeader.jsx(web.browser)
"babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/imports/adminDashboard/dashboard/components/AdminHeader.jsx(web.browser)
"react" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/lib/adminRoutes.js (web.browser)
"react-mounter" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/lib/adminRoutes.js (web.browser)
"react-dom" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/imports/adminDashboard/dashboard/components/AdminHeader.jsx(web.browser)
"prop-types" in /home/ubuntu/meteor/ECSystems/imports/adminDashboard/dashboard/components/DashboardLayout.jsx(web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

meteor npm install --save babel-runtime react react-mounter react-dom
prop-types
```

So, I tried running the following command,

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime react react-mounter react-dom prop-types
```

Which results in

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 49708

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-01-30T19_26_50_381Z-
debug.log
```

What to do? Not getting where I am getting wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your app directory then rm package.lock did the trick. After that I installed all the react related npm packages and deployment is successful.
[This](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17340) link helped me. Thank you.

```
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Prepare Bundle
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Prepare Bundle: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Configuring App
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Pushing the Startup Script
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Sending Environment Variables
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Start Meteor
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Start Meteor: SUCCESS
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Verifying Deployment
[54.69.xxx.xxx] - Verifying Deployment: SUCCESS
```